# Is there a version of "pushd -n" that works if I change directories before the "popd"?

Tags: bash

`pushd` and `popd` are convenient when working with multiple directories. Sometimes I want to push a directory to be worked with later, without necessarily going there right away, which seems to be exactly what `pushd -n` was intended for

There's just one small problem - attempting to do that often results in `No such file or directory` messages at best, and scenarios like this at worst:

```
$ ls foo
Files  I  Want
$ pushd -n foo # I'll want to go there later
~ foo
$ cd bar # But I have other things to do first
$ # ... doing other things ...
$ # Done! Now, I want to go back to foo
$ popd # Fortunately I placed that on the dir stack earlier
~/bar/foo
$ ls
"Wait, this isn't where I wanted to end up"
```

Is there a workaround to get the ability to store a directory on the stack, without moving me into that directory until I `popd` to it later, and allowing me to do that even if I move to a different directory in the meantime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify an absolute path:

```
pushd -n $PWD/foo

pd() { pushd -n "$(realpath "$1")"; }
```

Comment: The first works, but having to remember to do that for every `pushd -n` is what I'm here to try to avoid. The second seems to resolve symlinks, which I don't want - I expect `cd ~/foo && pushd -n bar` to push "~/foo/bar" even if `~/foo` is actually a symlink to `/tmp/baz`

Comment: Use `realpath -s`.